# Proof of a theorem in Hilbert System

Tags: logic

How to prove the following formula in Hilbert system:

$\vdash (A \to (B \to C)) \to ((A \land B) \to C)$

I have already proved out that

$\vdash (A \to (B \to C)) \to ((A \land B) \to (B \to C)) $

$\vdash (A \to C) \to ((A \land B) \to C) $

$\vdash (B \to C) \to ((A \land B) \to C) $

But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: You need $(A \land B) \to A$ and $(A \land B) \to B$

Comment: yes, I know. I used these to get the last three formula that close to the goal, but I cannot get the goal.

Comment: And Deduction Th, of course. Assume $(A \to (B \to C))$ and $A \land B$. Using the above rules derive $A$ and $B$ and by Modus Ponens derive $C$ from the first assumption.

Comment: Are there more details?

Comment: Are you allowed to use deduction theorem?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Yes, of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @MauroALLEGRANZA, the best solution is to show first that $A \to (B \to C), \, A \land B \vdash C$ is derivable. Indeed, the following is a derivation in Hilbert system of $C$ from the hypotheses $A \to (B \to C)$ and $A \land B$.

\begin{align}
1.& \quad A \to (B \to C) & \text{premise} \\
2.& \quad A \land B & \text{premise} \\
3.& \quad (A \land B) \to A & \text{axiom} \\
4.& \quad A &\text{modus ponens from 3 and 2} \\
5.& \quad B \to C & \text{modus ponens from 1 and 4} \\
6.& \quad (A \land B) \to B & \text{axiom} \\
7.& \quad B &\text{modus ponens from 6 and 2} \\
8.& \quad C &\text{modus ponens from 5 and 7} \\
\end{align}

By [deduction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem), from the fact that $A \to (B \to C), \, A \land B \vdash C$ is derivable it follows that $A \to (B \to C) \vdash (A \land B) \to C$ is derivable.

Again by deduction theorem, from the fact that $A \to (B \to C) \vdash (A \land B) \to C$ is derivable it follows that $\vdash (A \to (B \to C)) \to ((A \land B) \to C)$ is derivable.

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot to use deduction theorem which is important to solve this problem.